# How can I check the download source of a App that is downloaded from a server

Tags: java, android-studio, android-security

In my app, I am downloading some components of the app directly from the server, but then I want to check the download source to know if those components were actually downloaded from that server. I thought of using `getInstallerPackageName()` but that only works for apps like the play store. Please what approach can I use to resolve this? I was thinking of checking the URL. But don't really know how to implement it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what type of components you are downloading from the server directly.
If it is a file you can add file integrity checks, checksum, etc.
If you need to validate the source then you can create an allow list of servers, authorization headers and also add certificate checks if you need additional layer of security.